# Get random API file name in text file PHP and display it as function in HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to catch API name in text file by random using PHP, I have stored all API names in a textfile and randomize it in PHP:

In textfile:

```
 Api1.php
 Api2.php
 Api3.php
```

---

```
 <?php

function getapi()
{
  $nameofapi= file("testapi.txt");
  $randapi= rand(0, sizeof($nameofapi) - 1);
  $nameofapi = $nameofapi[$randapi];
  return $nameofapi;
}
$api= getapi();

echo $api;

?>
```

Now, I have a code in HTML function that gets the API directly from local file it looks like:

```
function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api.php?lista=' + value,
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(resultado) {
                        if (resultado.match("#Aprovada")) {
                            removelinha();
                            ap++;
                            aprovadas(resultado + "");
                        }else {
                            removelinha();
                            rp++;
                            reprovadas(resultado + "");
                        }
                        $('#carregadas').html(total);
                        var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                        $('#cLive').html(ap);
                        $('#cDie').html(rp);
                        $('#total').html(fila);
                        $('#cLive2').html(ap);
                        $('#cDie2').html(rp);
                    }
                });
            },
```

Is it possible to randomize "api.php" name via text file so that it will change the button's API function randomly?

Comment: What is `value` supposed to hold in your code?

Comment: it holds specific numbers to check into every api. Every api has different functions to check. I want to have one button to randomly chose an api to check the specified value of the user input.